# Rotate a groupd of objects around the CG of a bounding box

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to rotate objects around the cg of bounding box, but they are still rotating around the [0,0,0] origin.
The code is shown below :

```
import React, { forwardRef, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { objects, library, building } from "./config";
import Block from "./Block";
import { TransformControls, useHelper } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Box3, BoxHelper, LineSegments, Vector3 } from "three";
import { VertexNormalsHelper } from "three/examples/jsm/helpers/VertexNormalsHelper";

import { useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Selection } from "./Selection";
import { useControls } from "leva";
const BlockContainer = (props, ref) => {
  const { gl } = useThree();

  const [File, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [SelectedObjects, setSelectedObjects] = useState([]);
  const [AllBlocks, setAllBlocks] = useState([]);
  const [CG, setCG] = useState([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]);

  const { mode, ...config } = useControls({
    mode: { options: ["translate", "rotate"] },
  });

  const blockRefs = useRef([]);
  const selectedRef = useRef();
  const unselectedRef = useRef();
  const transformRef = useRef();
  const rotationRef = useRef();
  const helperRef = useRef();

  // helpers
  useHelper(selectedRef, BoxHelper, "green");
  useHelper(true, BoxHelper, "red");
  useHelper(true, VertexNormalsHelper, "blue");

  useEffect(() => {
    setFile(objects);
  }, []);

  const initBlocks = (bref) => {
    setAllBlocks((prev) => [...prev, bref.current]);
  };

  const getCenter = (objects) => {
    const center = objects
      .map((i) => [
        i?.matrixWorld.elements[12] || 0.0,
        i?.matrixWorld.elements[13] || 0.0,
        i?.matrixWorld.elements[14] || 0.0,
      ])
      .reduce(
        (acc, curr) => [acc[0] + curr[0], acc[1] + curr[1], acc[2] + curr[2]],
        [0, 0, 0]
      )
      .map((sum) => sum / objects.length);

    return center;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (SelectedObjects.length > 1) {
      const center = getCenter(SelectedObjects);

      const center1 = [
        center[0] -
          transformRef.current.offset.x -
          transformRef.current.positionStart.x,
        center[1] -
          transformRef.current.offset.y -
          transformRef.current.positionStart.y,
        center[2] -
          transformRef.current.offset.z -
          transformRef.current.positionStart.z,
      ];

      setCG(center);

      AllBlocks.forEach((b) => {
        if (SelectedObjects.includes(b)) {
          selectedRef.current.attach(b);
        } else {
          unselectedRef.current.attach(b);
          selectedRef.current.remove(b);
        }
      });

      transformRef.current.attach(selectedRef.current);
    } else if (SelectedObjects.length === 1) {
      transformRef.current.attach(SelectedObjects[0]);
    }
  }, [SelectedObjects, AllBlocks, mode]);

  return (
    <>
      <Block
        data={building.coreshell}
        url={library[building.coreshell.itemId].url}
        onSelect={(sel) => {}}
        key={building.coreshell.id}
        onInit={(bref) => {}}
        Offset={new Vector3(0, 0, 0)}
      />

      <TransformControls
        ref={transformRef}
        onChange={(ev) => {}}
        onMouseUp={(ev) => {
          console.log("position", transformRef.current.position);
          console.log("positionStart", transformRef.current.positionStart);
          console.log("offset", transformRef.current.offset);
        }}
        mode={mode}
        enabled={SelectedObjects.length > 0}
        scale={SelectedObjects.length > 0 ? 0.5 : 0.0}
      />

      <group ref={selectedRef} />
      <group ref={unselectedRef} />

      {building.blocks.map((i, index) => (
        <Block
          data={i}
          Offset={null}
          url={library[i.itemId].url}
          onInit={initBlocks}
          exSelected={false}
          onSelect={(sel) => {
            setSelectedObjects((prev) => {
              if (prev.includes(sel.current)) {
                return prev.filter((h) => h !== sel.current);
              } else {
                return [...prev, sel.current];
              }
            });
          }}
          key={`block_togo_${i.id}`}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default BlockContainer;
```

I have trying getting the center vector of the selected objects, then move the `<TransformControls ../>` into that position. I expected that the group of objects will rotate around this center. but what happens is that they rotate around the origin.